# c# wanting to pipeline the output from atmel studio command line to command prompt

Tags: c#, command-line, console-application, pipeline, atmelstudio

I want to automate the flashing of hardware using the command prompt. I have checked to see if the strings passed to the command prompt from atprogram.exe are correct and now have narrowed it down to my output

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Diagnostics;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using System.IO;

 namespace AutoFlash
 {
 class Program
 {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string atProgramLocaction = "\"C:\\Program Files 
        (x86)\\Atmel\\Studio\\7.0\\atbackend\\atprogram.exe\"";
        string atProgramArgs = "-t atmelice -i swd -d DEVICENAME program 
        -f";
        string fileLocation = "C\:\FILE.HEX";

        string command = atProgramLocaction + " " + atProgramArgs + " " + 
        fileLocation;

        Process AtmelCommand = new Process();
        AtmelCommand.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        AtmelCommand.StartInfo.Arguments = command;
        AtmelCommand.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        AtmelCommand.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        AtmelCommand.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        AtmelCommand.Start();

        Console.WriteLine(AtmelCommand.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
        AtmelCommand.WaitForExit();

    }
  }
}
```

Ideally would like to see the atmel command line output "Firmware check OK
Programming completed successfully" passed to cmd.exe and printed to confirm to user that firmware flashed successfully. What is currently happening is a blank command line window popping up.Any help with this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

A few things; the output may be coming on `StandardError` instead of `StandardOut`, also, I think you need to read the streams after the `WaitForExit`.

Try something like this:-

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();

psi.FileName = "program.exe";
psi.Arguments = "-v";
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardError = true;

var p = Process.Start(psi);

var stdout = string.Empty;
var stderr = string.Empty;

p.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
{
    stderr += e.Data;
};

p.BeginErrorReadLine();

string line;

while ((line = p.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    stdout += line;
}

p.WaitForExit();

Console.WriteLine(stdout);
Console.WriteLine(stderr);
Console.WriteLine(p.ExitCode);
```